# Expanding tableview sections on clicking each section

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a tableview which has 2 sections and some cells(which can be dynamic)below each section showing associated data.

This is the code I have written to show the data...

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    if section == 0 {
      return recentUsers?.count
    } else {
      return groupNameArray?.count
    }

  }


func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
     return 2
}




 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    if section == 0 {
      return "  CHAT LIST"
    } else {
      return "  GROUPS"
    }
  }




 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! RecentMessageCell
    cell.tag = indexPath.row

    if indexPath.section == 0 {

        if let user = recentChatUsers?[indexPath.row] {
          cell.idLabel?.text = user.id

      }
    } else {


      if groupNameArray.isEmpty == false {
       let grpArr = groupNameArray[indexPath.row]
       cell.userNameLabel?.text = grpArr.grpname
      }
    }

    return cell
  }
```

Now what I want to achieve is if I click on the first section, it should expand and show the cells it contains and the same should happen with the second cell also. Clicking on each of those sections again should hide the cells that were expanded.

I did search the internet for solutions. But though there were resources available, I couldn't find much help for my problem...

Comment: You can follow this example https://github.com/kamirana4/SwiftComponents

Comment: No, its not third party. Just see the implementation of `ExpandableTableViewExample ` and do it yourself.

Comment: ya..:) had a look at it.. hence deleted my comment...:)

Comment: you can follow this https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/ios-how-to-build-a-table-view-with-collapsible-sections-96badf3387d0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add an array to keep track of section expend/collapse

```
let sectionStats = [Bool](repeating: true, count: 2)
```

Add a, IBAction to track section tap, update value of `sectionStats` for the corresponding section and reload section

and update your `numberOfRowsInSection` as show below

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        guard sectionStats[section] else {
            return 0
        }

        if section == 0 {
            return 1
        } else {
            return list.count
        }
    }
```

Tappable Header:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    return headerView(section: section, title: section == 0  ? "CHAT LIST" : "GROUPS")
}

private func headerView(section: Int, title: String) -> UIView {
    let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect.zero)
    button.tag = section
    button.setTitle(title, for: .normal)
    button.setTitleColor(UIColor.red, for: .normal)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(sectionHeaderTapped), for: .touchUpInside)

    return button
}

@objc private func sectionHeaderTapped(sender: UIButton) {
    let section = sender.tag
    sectionStats[section] = !sectionStats[section]
    tableView.beginUpdates()
    tableView.reloadSections([section], with: .automatic)
    tableView.endUpdates()
}
```

Good tutorial on **How to build a Table View with Collapsible Sections**:
https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/ios-how-to-build-a-table-view-with-collapsible-sections-96badf3387d0

Comment: but how do i set up the IBAction on the default section..?

Comment: @user308123, you can use custom header.

Comment: Thanks @Satish...I'll try...:)

Comment: It did work @Satish. Thanks a lot...! But I would like to have the that button comes up in the middle of the section to be in the extreme left of the section. Also, would you mind explaining what this line does in numberOfRowsInSection `guard sectionStats[section] else {
            return 0
        }`

Comment: `button.contentHorizontalAlignment = .left` to align button content left. this will returns 0 if for collaspe state `sectionStats[section] == false`

Comment: Thanks @Satish..But excuse me for asking again...I actually didn't quite get what exactly you meant by `this will returns 0 if for collaspe state sectionStats[section] == false`..Would you also maybe mind explaining in a line or so as to what exactly your boolean array does..?..because I have not worked with boolean arrays before..please excuse me for bothering...:)

Comment: Got it @Satish..Thanks..have given an upvote too...:)

Comment: `sectionStats` array keeps a record for the expanded/collapsed state of a section. Initially, all sections are in the expended state i.e. `sectionStats = [true, true]`. Tap over a section header will toggle its state and reload corresponding section (example: tap over first section header will result  `sectionStats = [false, true]`)

Comment: Ok..Thanks again @Satish..:) can't give an upvote due to the low reputation..:(

Answer (score 0):

This kind of feature requires a bit more code and I cannot write the whole code here but I can explain you the concepts that will be used to achieve this and will attach a few good tutorials which I used to ultimately create a feature like this

---

1. First you need to create a *custom* `HeaderView` for your *sections*
2. Next you need a `UITapGestureRecognizer` on your section and need to write your login inside the *function* provided in `action` part of `UITapGestureRecognizer`'s constructor

> 3. You need to create a separate `Protocol` inside your `HeaderView` file and your `ViewController` that contains your `TableView` will adopt to that protocol and will handle whether to expand or collapse your rows

4. Also, you will need to create a separate `Struct` instance for each *section* which will contain a `boolean variable` that will indicate whether that section is expanded or collapsed

That is the basic concept that will be needed while creating `Expandable List` in iOS.

Below I have attached links to some of the tutorials :

[Tutorial 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q8k9E1gQ_qg)

[Tutorial 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ClrSpJ3txAs)

[Tutorial 3](https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/ios-how-to-build-a-table-view-with-collapsible-sections-96badf3387d0)

[Tutorial 4](https://www.appcoda.com/expandable-table-view/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Shubham Bakshi...:)